# why cannot find composer.phar file after install composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-routing

I try to install composer with the installer for Windows , but could not be installed globally.

The message:

> Could not open input file: c:\windows\system32\composer.phar

I have to run on the following url:

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;
```

My environment variables are:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;
```

How can I install composer globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

composer.phar is a single file, you can just move it to the system32 folder and have it visible globally

Comment: yes but why cannot execute composer.phar from any place

Answer (score 2):

It's not in your path. Check environmental variables.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you had it already installed in global path, its yours mentioned 
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin; you just had to restart windows or command line window in order to global environment path to take effect.

You can find composer.phar very easily with very good tool called listary as i did by the way. It uses some proprietary very effective fuzzy search heuristics and for me basically could find almost any file i wanted anytime.